how to append validation accuracy for each epoch in the code below?
def train():
seed_val = 42
criterion = CosineSimilarityLoss()
criterion = criterion.to(device)
random.seed(seed_val)
torch.manual_seed(seed_val)
We'll store a number of quantities such as training and validation loss,
validation accuracy, and timings.
training_stats = []
total_t0 = time.time()
for epoch_i in range(0, epochs):
  # ========================================
  #               Training
  # ========================================

  print("")
  print('======== Epoch {:} / {:} ========'.format(epoch_i + 1, epochs))
  print('Training...')

  t0 = time.time()

  total_train_loss = 0

  model.train()

  # For each batch of training data...
  for train_data, train_label in tqdm(train_dataloader):

      train_data['input_ids'] = train_data['input_ids'].to(device)
      train_data['attention_mask'] = train_data['attention_mask'].to(device)

      train_data = collate_fn(train_data)
      model.zero_grad()

      output = [model(feature) for feature in train_data]

      loss = criterion(output, train_label.to(device))
      total_train_loss += loss.item()

      loss.backward()
      torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
      optimizer.step()
      scheduler.step()

  
  # Calculate the average loss over all of the batches.
  avg_train_loss = total_train_loss / len(train_dataloader)            
  
  # Measure how long this epoch took.
  training_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)

  print("")
  print("  Average training loss: {0:.5f}".format(avg_train_loss))
  print("  Training epoch took: {:}".format(training_time))
      
  # ========================================
  #               Validation
  # ========================================

  print("")
  print("Running Validation...")

  t0 = time.time()

  model.eval()

  total_eval_accuracy = 0
  total_eval_loss = 0
  nb_eval_steps = 0

  # Evaluate data for one epoch
  for val_data, val_label in tqdm(validation_dataloader):

      val_data['input_ids'] = val_data['input_ids'].to(device)
      val_data['attention_mask'] = val_data['attention_mask'].to(device)

      val_data = collate_fn(val_data)

      with torch.no_grad():        
          output = [model(feature) for feature in val_data]

      loss = criterion(output, val_label.to(device))
      total_eval_loss += loss.item()

  # Calculate the average loss over all of the batches.
  avg_val_loss = total_eval_loss / len(validation_dataloader)
  
  # Measure how long the validation run took.
  validation_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)
  
  print("  Validation Loss: {0:.5f}".format(avg_val_loss))
  print("  Validation took: {:}".format(validation_time))

  # Record all statistics from this epoch.
  training_stats.append(
      {
          'epoch': epoch_i + 1,
          'Training Loss': avg_train_loss,
          'Valid. Loss': avg_val_loss,
          'Training Time': training_time,
          'Validation Time': validation_time
      }
  )

print("")
print("Training complete!")
print("Total training took {:} (h:mm:ss)".format(format_time(time.time()-total_t0)))
return model, training_stats
in my function code, after running the train process some quantities are saved like training loss, validation loss and time spent for each epoch.
In the evaluation section of the code , you see     "  total_eval_accuracy = 0" .
but the code does not provide any accuracy and does not return accruacy in the last line.
so my question is how to see and store accuracy of each epoch ?
and is there any way I can store some of other evaluation metrics like precision and recall also?
